# How to check if R network proxy settings work?

Tags: r, proxy, cran

I have no practical experience with the R language itself but I've been tasked to install it behind a corporate firewall. Basic installation seems sane but when my user tries to install a custom library like this:

```
install.packages("ggplot2")
Installing package into '/home/myuser/rlibs'
(as 'lib' is unspecified)
Warning: unable to access index for repository http://cran.us.r-project.org/src/contrib
Warning message:
package 'ggplot2' is not available (for R version 3.1.2)
```

I see no progress and eventually nothing gets downloaded into my custom directory. My question is, there is a way to add verbosity to R to see if the network proxy setting are working correctly (I can get files with wget without problems under the same account)?

More details about my installation

- I'm behind a firewall with http proxy access
- I have no root and made a local installation

Contents of my `~/.Renviron`

```
R_LIBS=/home/myuser/rlibs
```

Contents of `~/.Rprofile`

```
r <- getOption("repos") # hard code the US repo for CRAN
r["CRAN"] <- "http://cran.us.r-project.org"
options(repos = r)
rm(r)
```

Http proxy is set (like `http_proxy=XXXXproxy.XXXX.com`. I can see it if I do `Sys.getenv("http_proxy")` from inside the R prompt)

Comment: I managed to install libraries 'by hand' but for module that have dependencies this doesn't work:

`cd /home/$USER/rlibs/;
wget http://cran.us.r-project.org/src/contrib/timeDate_3011.99.tar.gz;
/mylocal/R-3.1.2/bin/R CMD INSTALL -l /localrdir timeDate_3011.99.tar.gz`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the issue, the problem was the format of the `http_proxy` variable.

Incorrect: `http_proxy="servername"`

Correct: `http_proxy="http://servername:80"`

Thanks to all who took the time to check this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting this in your script as well, e.g.

```
Sys.setenv(http_proxy="http://servername:80")
```

Sometimes I have to do this as well for some API's to work, even though it is set in Rprofile.

Comment: Sorry, your suggestion didn't help.