# Installing package stringi: icudt could not be downloaded. check your internet connectivity

Tags: r, r-package

I was trying to install `stringi` on R and I have this error:
on R gui interface

```
icudt download failed
Error in eval(ei, envir) : 
  icudt could not be downloaded. check your internet connectivity
* removing 'C:/Users/zzaroca/AppData/Local/Programs/R/R-4.2.0/library/stringi'
Warning message:
In install.packages(files[tarballs], .libPaths()[1L], repos = NULL,  :
```

and this on R studio:

```
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.2:
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.2/PACKAGES'
```

What I can do to solve this problem? My connection to internet works perfectly and I'm trying to install on my company's computer.

Comment: Can you access this `https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.2/PACKAGES` from your browser directly? Maybe you are behind a firewall?

Comment: Yes I can access it directly from my browser.

Comment: Maybe check your [proxy settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27911144/how-to-check-if-r-network-proxy-settings-work)

Comment: cause I have already installed tons of other packages like 'ggplot'' and so, downloading them directly from the Cran page and they worked 'stringi' is the only one with a problem .-.

Comment: How about [this](https://community.rstudio.com/t/install-packages-unable-to-access-index-for-repository-try-disabling-secure-download-method-for-http/16578)?

Comment: done but the problem persist on r console and R studio